# 'mean' of logit-normal distribution

Tags: mean

$ X \sim N(\mu,\sigma^2) $

$ Y = \frac{\exp(X)}{1+\exp(X)} $

Y has a logit-normal distribution.

When I have a correct estimate of the mean, say $\bar{Y}$, of the logit-normal distribution,
how can use it to get a correct estimate of $\mu$ ?

I don't have full sample from logit-normal distribution, but only the correct estimate of the mean.
I know that $ \log(\dfrac{\bar{Y}}{1-\bar{Y}}) $ is not the right answer due to Jensen's inequality.

Comment: You say:  "I have a correct estimate of the mean of $Y$", /// Do you actually intend to say that you "_have a correct estimate of the mean_":  i.e.  $E[Y]$, OR that you have an unbiased estimator of the mean of $Y$? Not the same.

Comment: Yes, I meant that I have an unbiased estimator of the mean of Y.

Comment: You are basically asking to solve for $\mu$ given $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \sigma^2}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^x}{1+e^x} e^{-(x-\mu)^2/(2\sigma^2)} dx = \bar{Y}$. According to mathematica, there is no closed form solution of the integral in terms of $\mu$ and $\sigma$ in general, so your best shot is probably to use some numerical solver, such as Newton's method.

Comment: A common approach to what I *think* you're asking about would be to approximately unbias the estimate via use of [Taylor expansion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_expansions_for_the_moments_of_functions_of_random_variables). But on the other hand, I think too much is made of bias. If you have ML estimates on the transformed scale, they'll remain ML after transformation back.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The integral appearing here is the so-called logistic-normal integral. Denoting it as
\begin{equation}
\varphi(\mu,\sigma) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{1+e^{-x}} e^{-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}(x-\mu)^2}
\end{equation}

then one needs to solve the equation $\varphi(\mu,\sigma) = \bar Y$. One must  assume that $\sigma$ is known in order to be able to solve this equation.

One can show that $\varphi(\mu,\sigma)$ can be computed exactly at $\mu = 0, \pm \sigma^2, \pm 2 \sigma^2, \cdots $. This was shown in [Pirjol (2013)](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0377042712002518).

(The integral is a limiting case of the Mordell integral from analytic number theory, and has many surprising symmetry properties.)
Then it is just a matter of bracketing $\bar Y$ between two points on the grid of spacing $\sigma^2$, and solving for $\mu$.

**References**

Pirjol, D. (2013). "[The logistic-normal integral and its generalizations](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0377042712002518)." *Journal of Computational and Applied Mathematics*, **237**(1), 460-469.

Comment: Welcome to our site! It's a good idea to put full citations/references to an article rather than just a bare link, as you would in a paper or similar. That gives a degree of protection if publishers ever move links around, and also makes it easier for readers to spot a paper or author they recognise than the URL does!